# How can I reduce the dimensions of gif images with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

What flag in `magick.exe convert <flags>` will reduce the dimensions of my image?

This is the command I'm using: `magick.exe input.png[0] -depth 8 -type Grayscale -dresize 400x300`.

The `[0]` after the source-image filename is meant to strip the first frame of any animated gifs.

How can I do reduce my output gif sizes?  My file sizes are too large: my outputs need to be less than 100k.  Any methods other than reducing the dimensions are also welcome.

Comment: If a single frame, use -colors to reduce the number of colors in the colormap. If animated, then use -layers Optimize and also apply the same colormap to each frame using -remap.

Answer (score 59):

```
convert test.gif -fuzz 10% -layers Optimize result.gif
```

Adding a -fuzz 2% produced a better optimization, but still not very good. At -fuzz 15% It isolated the differences for frame optimization to just the visible color band changes I noted before. 
At 25% the differences were almost to just the text changes.

Finally at a massive 30% fuzz factor (ignore color changes below that figure, did it optimize to just the text changes.

Comment: I have a huge gif, (42 MB) this eats up all of my 16 GB ram and locks the computer.

Answer (score 26):

You can try `gifsicle`:

```
gifsicle -O3 old.gif -o new.gif
```

If it's an animation, you could try skipping frames (see [how it works](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20937)).

Comment: ```gifsicle -O4 old.gif -o new.gif --colors 64```

Answer (score 1):

`magick.exe convert -resize 100x100 .\step1.jpg .\step2.jpg -delay 100 -loop 0 animation.gif`

Thanks to Nate.

```
//IMPORTANT: -resize should come first.
//BY DEFAULT: the aspect ratio will be locked with the longest dimension being set to 100px.
//GENERALIZATION: this order `magick convert 1st<input_file(s)> 2nd<switch(es)> 3rd<output_file>`.
//IMPORTANT-RELATED: `-delay` will not work on second brush!  Use `-set delay` for existing files.
```

Please, also be sure to **refresh your folder view to ensure that you're not viewing old output files**: Windows Explorer (<kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: This is bad ImageMagick 7 syntax. First, use magick.exe, not magick.exe convert. Second, input should be read before any commands such as -resize. Finally, the OP said he wanted methods other than changing the dimensions. So -resize is not what he wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but you can just edit the answer, @fmw42.  Also, `-resize` is what he wanted, specifically, and he also asked for other methods of reducing the file size: "My sizes are too big." - op.  I used this syntax because it's similar to the manual, but I agree that inputs should come first.

Comment: fwiw I ended up just converting the gif I'd already made with `convert -resize 100x100 old.gif new.gif` instead of recreating in the above manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the option:

> -type Palette

It might help to reduce your gif file sizes smaller, oh and I believe -depth 8 can only be used for png images.

Comment: In my case, `-type Palette` didn't change anything.