# Best way to compress animated GIFs using ImageMagick, without using Gifsicle

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif

So my web host won't install `gifsicle` on their shared servers, so I'm stuck with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). I want to compress the images like it is here: https://pornel.net/lossygif how can I do that without using `gifsicle`; using only ImageMagick?

Right now my `exec()` command goes like:

```
exec("convert $animation -coalesce -gravity SouthWest  -geometry +0+0 null: $watermark -layers composite -layers optimize $animation");
```

and the watermarked GIF barely compresses, and sometimes it even gets larger.
How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 24):

I had success with ImageMagick's Mogrify:
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

After you generate a large gif, you can make it smaller.

My command looked like:

```
mogrify -layers 'optimize' -fuzz 7% mygif.gif
```

The `-layers` option optimized any layers in your gif

The biggest space savings comes from the `-fuzz` option, which specifies that colors within a certain tolerance can be considered the same color.

My several second gifs went from 3 MB to a few hundred kb.

Comment: The `-fuzz` flag really did it for me, as well. Thanks for the specific usage tip!

Comment: Why does it leave last frames shadow behind.

Comment: For me, this command made the .gif actually bigger by about 70 KB.

Comment: This did a nice job of compressing but left ghost afterimages that were unacceptable. Ezgif compression got a similar size but no ghost artifacts.

Answer (score -5):

converts gif files online without code.

http://www.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi

If you want to use code why not use

`-quality 80% old.gif new.gif`

This should reduce the file size

---

Answer taken from:

[How can I compress the size of gif images with ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578926/how-can-i-compress-the-size-of-gif-images-with-imagemagick)

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578926/how-can-i-compress-the-size-of-gif-images-with-imagemagick`